# Number of months between given months

Tags: php

I want to find the count of number of months between given months such as Jan,Feb,Mar...

eg - Input - Jun , Aug 
 Output -3
Input - Dec,Mar
Output - 4

```
 $string = "Jun";
 $month_number1 = date("n",strtotime($string));
 $string = "Aug";
 $month_number2 = date("n",strtotime($string));
 $monthCount = ($month_number2 - $month_number1) +1 ;
```

But this doesn't work for Dec and Mar .
Please help.Thank you

Comment: Just work work mod 12

Comment: How ? 12 mod 3 gives 0 @JohnColeman

Comment: Apply the mod to the *difference*. @Octopus spells it out nicely in their answer.

Comment: Yes got it! Thank you :) @JohnColeman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to cyclic quantities like this is to calc the modulus of your delta by the number of elements, in this case 12, for twelve months. So, basically

```
(m2 - m1) % 12
```

But many languages don't do mods on negative numbers very effectively, so add the same number into the difference calc:

```
n = (12 + m2 - m1) % 12
```

Comment: Right @Octopus you forgot to add 1 to the solution