# Find temporal range of months, rolling over year

Tags: r, date

I would like to determine the shortest number of consecutive months that encompass all months within a vector (the temporal range).

When the months are all in the middle of the year, this can fairly easily be accomplished:

```
mos_summer <- c(6, 5, 6, 7, 9)
# desired answer: 5 months (May-September) encompass all values in mos_summer

max(mos_summer) - min(mos_summer) + 1  # produces 5 (correct!)
```

However, this approach breaks down when months are around the beginning/end of the year.

```
mos_winter <- c(12, 11, 1, 1, 12)
# desired answer: 3 months (November-January) encompass all values in mos_winter

max(mos_winter) - min(mos_winter) + 1  # produces 12 (wrong!)
```

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954044/number-of-months-between-given-months) demonstrates a solution in php using `mod`; however, this does not seem to work in R:

```
(12 + max(mos_winter) - min(mos_winter) + 1) %% 12  # produces 0
```

Does anyone know a good way to calculate temporal ranges, dealing with the beginning/end of a year?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. In the first example you write *"5 months (May-September) encompass all values in mos_summer)"* But there is no month = 8 in `mos_summer`. So why is 5 months the desired answer?

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers - sorry, let me clarify. Another way to phrase it is that I am looking for the temporal range; so, even if there is not an occurrence in every month, the shortest range which includes all occurrences. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok got it, thanks; perhaps you want to change the phrase *"shortest number of consecutive months"* because months don't have to be consecutive. The range is determined by min/max of `mos_winter`.

Comment: Would your list of months ever go over a year (i.e., result in a >12 month result) and is the vector arranged monotonically?

Comment: @zack - there will never be a value > 12 (or < 1). My input vectors are not arranged monotonically, but I imagine that could be done with some combination of `unique` and `sort`...

Comment: @SamZipper How do you know that `mos_winter` doesn't actually refer to the range Jan to Dec? Or to put it the other way around: How would you expect a vector to look if it *did* cover the range Jan to Dec? This is ambiguous, especially since you say that numbers are not arranged monotonically.

Comment: [continued] For example, what are the expected outputs for the vectors `c(1, 3, 11)` and `c(1, 11, 12)`? The first one could be Jan to Nov, or it could be Nov to Mar. The second could be Jan to Dec, or Nov to Jan.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - for `c(1, 3, 11)` I would expect `5` (Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar is the shortest number of consecutive months including Jan, Mar, and Nov). For `c(1, 11, 12)` I would expect `3` (Nov, Dec, Jan).

Comment: I guess an extreme case would be `c(1, 7)`. The desired answer is `7` but it could be counted either (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul) or (Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan). So I am not worried about the order of the input numbers, if that helps clarify.

Comment: @SamZipper Right, I think I got it now;-) Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Looks like it is working great- thanks!

Comment: Great; glad we got there @SamZipper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
mos_summer <- c(6, 5, 6, 7, 9)
mos_winter <- c(12, 11, 1, 1, 12)

min.month.range <- function(x) {
    x1 <- x
    x2 <- ifelse(x <= 6, x + 12, x)
    min(diff(range(x1)) + 1, diff(range(x2)) + 1)
}

min.month.range(mos_summer)
#[1] 5

min.month.range(mos_winter)
#[1] 3

min.month.range(c(1, 3, 11))
#[1] 5

min.month.range(c(1, 11, 12))
#[1] 3

min.month.range(c(1, 7))
#[1] 7
```